GeoServer Querylayer plugin exception max number of collected
Filtering query:
INTERSECTS(the_geom, collectGeometries(queryCollection('sphaera:municipality_area', 'the_geom', 'INCLUDE')));INCLUDE

Problem: geometry that is too complex generates a string that is too large for Java to handle. Is it possible to fix this?
querylayer-plugin-2.13.4
Java error :
java lang IllegalStateException: Max number of collected ordinates has been exceeded
Current count is 37489, max count is 37449
Max number of collected ordinates has been exceeded.
Current count is 37489, max count is 37449


Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. Please [Edit] your Question to contain the error as text. Images are not legible on all devices and the error cannot be searched for by others (giving the impression you only want the answer for yourself, not for others with the same issue)

Welcome Vlad !
You can fix it by setting JVM startup option / variable GEOMETRY_COLLECT_MAX_COORDINATES.
See the docs here : https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/extensions/querylayer/index.html#memory-limits
